# Does the position of ∃ matter?

Tags: predicate-logic

> Everyone who makes an A aces some final exam

Is this

```
∀x,∃y: makes(x, A) => aces(x, y)
```

the same as

```
∀x: makes(x, A) => ∃y: aces(x, y)
```

where x represents everyone and y represents exams.

**Does the position of `∃` matter?**

Comment: In this case both are equivalent, however, it is **not** the case for ∀x,∃y P(x,y) and ∃y,∀x P(x,y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are equivalent.

This is part of a theorem called "[Prenex normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Implication)".

Answer (score 0):

Let $M=\{x\mid\text{makes}(x,A)\}$ and $E$ the set of exams. Then, both assertions are equivalent to:
$$
\forall x\in M,\quad\exists y\in E,\quad\text{aces}(x,y).
$$